# Password promt twice at Log In screen

Tags: 14.04, login, password

I am experiencing a problem when logging into my account. I’m using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The scenario is when I turn on my computer the Log In screen pops up as it should, I enter my password and it rejects it as if it were wrong, I enter it again and it allows me to log in. The problem is it never accepts my password the first time.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: ...and sometimes accepts it but still brings up the login screen again but this second attempt is successful.  No one seems to know the real reason all points to a bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1292451